# SVG Rendering in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, svg, filter, rendering

So, I've been working on a picture using some hand-written SVG code. Some of it is my own original work and some of it I copied and pasted from some tutorials.

My problem is that the file isn't rendering consistently between browsers or between image-editors. Here's my SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.2" height="75px">
 <defs id="wordDef">
  <filter id="outerbevel" x0="-50%" y0="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1" result="blur"/>
    <feOffset dy="1" dx="1"/>
    <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="1" k3="-1" result="hlDiff"/>
    <feFlood flood-color="white" flood-opacity=".7"/>
    <feComposite in2="hlDiff" operator="in"/>
    <feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="over" result="withGlow"/>
    <feOffset in="blur" dy="-1" dx="-1"/>
    <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="1" k3="-1" result="shadowDiff"/>
    <feFlood flood-color="black" flood-opacity="1"/>
    <feComposite in2="shadowDiff" operator="in" result="test1"/>
    <feComposite in2="withGlow" operator="over" result="test2"/>
    <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode in="test1"/>
      <feMergeNode in="test2"/>
      <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
 </defs>

<text x="0" y="23" font-size="23px" fill="#aaa" fill-opacity="1" filter="url(#outerbevel)">SERVICES</text>
</svg>
```

Google Chrome version

[image: Chrome version]

Compared to Firefox version

[image: Firefox version]

I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Edit: Cleaned up the mark-up as per Robert Longson's request.

Comment: Remove the markup a bit at a time till you figure out what exactly is different. There's shadows and filters and text-shadow etc. Once you have a simpler problem we can likely advise better.

Comment: Ok, I edited it so it's a lot cleaner. I took out the necessaries so all that you should be looking at are the essentials, at least, as far as I understand it.